# CakePHP - building a search - how to include URL vars in query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm building a search page that will have many different search parameters that the user can click on, which will pass the variables in the URL.

```
$this->Restaurant->recursive = 1;
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'City.name' => $this->params['url']['city'],
        'Cuisine.name' => $this->params['url']['cuisine'],
    ),
);
$data = $this->paginate('Restaurant');
$this->set('data', $data);
```

This works just fine IF there is ?city=newyork&cuisine=pizza in the URL - but if not, it errors out*  If it were normal PHP, I'd build out the query as a string and append conditions only if the variables existed...etc.  But with Cake I'm not sure where to begin or what would be the best way to manage this.

**EDIT:**

*If I do not have 'city' or 'cuisine' being passed as URL variables, I get this:

```
<b>Notice</b> (8)</a>: Undefined index:  city [<b>APP/controllers
/restaurants_controller.php</b>, line <b>18</b>

...

City.name'&nbsp;=&gt;&nbsp;$this-&gt;params['url']['city'],
</span></code></span></pre></div><pre class="stack-trace">
RestaurantsController::search() - APP/controllers/restaurants_controller.php
, line 18
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83
```

It wouldn't be a problem if I just had "city" and "cuisine" - but if I plan on having 20 more search options to be passed in the same way, I'd like to be able to pass them or not at my discretion instead of being forced to have them ALL in the URL every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean `errors out`?

Usually adding `$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));` before your pagination call in the *view* will make cake add all the passed URL params to the url that it generates

**EDIT**

What you're looking for are named parameters : http://book.cakephp.org/view/947/Named-parameters

If you look at the last example, you'll see that the route maps to `ContentsController->view();` with all the parameters you (optionally) chose to send available in the `passedArgs` array.

```
URL: /contents/view/chapter:models/section:associations
Mapping: ContentsController->view();
$this->passedArgs['chapter'] = 'models';
$this->passedArgs['section'] = 'associations';
$this->params['named']['chapter'] = 'models';
$this->params['named']['section'] = 'associations';
```

**EDIT 2**

Your problem here is that you have a variable set of search criteria. Your system should basically go through the search criteria and build your search query depending what filters have been chosen. There are several ways you can solve this. The easiest would be to loop through them.

```
$allowsFilters = array('city' => 'Model.city', 'name' => 'Model.name', 'price' => 'Model.price'); //list of allowed keys to search on. 
$opts  = array();
foreach ($this->params['named'] as $filter => $value)  {
    if (isset($allowsFilters[$filter])) {
         $opts[$allowsFilters[$filter]] = $value; 
    }
}
$findOpts = array('conditions' => $opts)
$this->Model->find('all', $findOpts);
```

This way, you're whitelisting a set of filters that can be applied. And you loop through the params and build your `conditions` array. You'll have to modify this a bit if you need OR conditions or different MYSQL. But this will allow you to have a variable number of filters.

Comment: Although I appreciate that piece of info, my question is - how do I deal with writing the conditions based on whether or not that variable exists.  I have so many different search options that will be passed through the URL (not sure whether to do it /var1/var2 or ?var1=xyz&var2=xyz), I don't want ALL to be required in the URL every time.

(Editing the question to include details of my errors)

Comment: @Dave much clearer now. What you need are named params. Don't have the parameters as part of the method signature. Simply access them from inside the action and not as a method parameter.

Comment: @JohnP - I believe your answer just told me how to GET the variable - which is good - I like params['named'] better than params['url'] - but it still gives me an error if I try to run my page without having "city" in the URL.

Comment: @Dave you'll obviously need to check whether it's set or not - `$city = (empty($this->params['named']['city'])) ? '' : $this->params['named']['city'];` Or you could just hand that cleanup logic to the model. Then you'd just pass the variables and not the array themselves (which is a bit bad to do in any case)

Comment: @JohnP - I realize my questions are probably stupid, but I'm just so used to normal PHP, and not used to CakePHP, that it's confusing to me.

I understand that I need to check if the variables exists, and build my query based on whether or not they exist - which I could do in 30 seconds in regular PHP.

But in CakePHP, although I CAN find out if the variable exists, I don't know where to go from there - how do I build my query in Cake?

Comment: @JohnP - I think I figured it out - I didn't realize in Cake, you could just send normal conditions in string format - I thought they had to be 'City.name' => 'new york' (or whatever).  That something you want to include or add to your answer so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: @Dave you can send normal conditions but keep in mind that cake does not apply SQL filtering to these conditions! So make sure to sanitize it. I updated my answer with a method you could use. No need to mark as answered if it didn't solve your problem :)

Comment: @JohnP - THAT (edit 2) is the answer I've been waiting for!  Thank you very much!  One minor change I had to make was - I couldn't send $findOpts - I had to just pass $opts like:  'conditions' => $opts

Comment: @Dave Yes, the array you built was the conditions array so how you pass it would depend on your setup. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

cake use MVC pattern, mean that url like http://localhost/controller/action/param1/param2
convert to index.php?controller=controller&action=action&param1=pararm1 ...

if you can't get the query string from the original url (http://localhost/controller.../?a=3&b=2)
you should add QSA param to your .htaccess, it should look something like that

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [**QSA**,L]
</IfModule>
```

and then you will get the query string to your action method.

if you don't want to use this way, you can get the params via the controller's action using

```
$arg_list = func_get_args();
```

in place of the query string

it will look something like that

```
Controller Pages{
  public function search(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $arg){
       // build query string for the search, depending on the params you got
    }
    // do search
  }

}
```

Comment: While this is totally correct in the context of normal PHP, you don't actually do this in CakePHP.